# terraform assign variable value to map field value or default if not exist

Tags: terraform

sorry for the basic question... But I could not find a more elegant way to solve this...

Input:

```
a = [
    { one=1, two=2, three=3},
    { two=2, three=3},
    { one=1, three=3},
]
```

In my script I have something like

```
locals {
    containers = [for i, c in var.a : merge(c, {
        field1    = contains(keys(c), "one") ? c.one : "not defined"
        field2    = contains(keys(c), "two") ? c.two : "not defined"
        field3    = contains(keys(c), "three") ? c.three : "not defined"
        lastfield = contains(keys(c), "one") ? (contains(keys(c), "two") ? "${c.one},${c.two}" : "${c.one}") : ""
    })]
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that ? Basically I want to add some fields to each element of the list and I have to check it the element has a certain field and use this value or a default.

Also "lastfield" should reference field1 and field2, not recheck if the field exists .

I think the way to go is to have some intermediate null_resources to calc field1, field2, field3 andu use those in lastfield, but that would not be optimal...

Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Thanks !

Comment: For nested default values, this is probably going to be the option for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I created a new function in terraform and a PR  :)